# It says "No Solr instance available when trying to clear the cache", should I reinstall that module?

Tags: search

In admin/reports/apachesolr/solr  "No Solr instance available when trying to clear the cache", should I reinstall that module? I can`t cope with setting up the search block to return the search result.

Answer (score 2):

First check whether your solr instance working properly or not. Goto http://localhost:8080**(your port)**/solr/admin/.
And in your site goto **admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/solr/edit** page and enter **SOLR SERVER URL** and click on test connection whether your solr instance working or not. If not try to re-install solr if there is not indexing.

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr and it does not work, what to change?